# SQL Server 2012: compare and subtract dates in join

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012, dateadd

I want to get the results of this join query which are in the last 30 days.

`V.[4501001]` contains the nvarchar dates in this format `dd/mm/yyyy`

Here is my query:

```
(select Distinct T.PId from [dbo].[TrialStatus] T inner join 
    form.TP_VISDATE V on T.pid = V.pid
    where T.cid = 1064 and T.sid = 300 and (Convert(NVARCHAR, V.[4501001], 103) < Convert(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),103)) and (Convert(NVARCHAR, V.[4501001], 103) > DATEADD(DD,-30,Convert(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),103))))
```

If I use `Convert(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),103)` I get false results because this

```
select DATEADD(Day,-30,Convert(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),103))
```

returns `2018-01-08 00:00:00.000` instead of the day 30 days before today

But if I use `GETDATE()` as is without conversion I get this error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Why are you converting `DATETIME` to `NVARCHAR` at all? Convert (or `TRY_CONVERT`) `V.[4501001]` to a `DATETIME` and continue calculating on that. (Also, [don't use `NVARCHAR` without a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).)

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you that worked! I was so stuck couldn't see that ...

Answer (score 0):

Convert the value to a date, not a string!

```
select Distinct T.PId
from [dbo].[TrialStatus] T inner join 
     form.TP_VISDATE V 
     on T.pid = V.pid
where T.cid = 1064 and
      T.sid = 300 and
      Convert(date, V.[4501001], 103) < Convert(date, GETDATE()) and
      Convert(date, V.[4501001], 103) > DATEADD(day, -30, Convert(date, GETDATE()));
```

Then, you can fix the data in your table.  Don't store dates as strings.  Store them using native types.